# Enum and switch help. Java learner

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement, runtime-error

I am a Java self-learner and got stuck on this problem. Have tried unreasonable amount of combinations and possible solutions, but ran into even more errors.

```
public class SeasonsSwitch {
    enum Season  {
            WINTER,
            SPRING,
            SUMMER,
            FALL
        }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String currentSeason;
        currentSeason = TextIO.getWord();
        switch (currentSeason){
            case WINTER:
            TextIO.put("Decemeber, January, February");
            break;
            case SPRING:
            TextIO.put("March, April, May");
            break;
            case SUMMER:
            TextIO.put("June, July, August");
            break;
            case FALL:
            TextIO.put("September, October, November");

        }

    }
}

error. cannot find symbol 
case WINTER
error. cannot find symbol 
case SPRING
error. cannot find symbol 
case SUMMER
error. cannot find symbol 
case FALL
```

Comment: You have to use the same type for the value provided to the `switch` and its `case` statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Season.valueOf` to convert the string representation of the enum constant into the enum constant.

```
Season s = Season.valueOf(currentSeason);
switch (s){
```

[`Enum.valueOf` tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/enum_valueof.htm)

> The java.lang.Enum.valueOf() method returns the enum constant of the specified enumtype with the specified name. The name must match exactly an identifier used to declare an enum constant in this type.

Comment: Note that if an invalid season is used, an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are passing a `String` to switch and checking Cases on `ENUM`. Hence the type mismatch.

Please make sure that both must be of same or convertable types.

Answer (score 1):

You have to match the same type provided in the switch statement in each case statement.

In your case, the value is a String, so each case statement should be of type string.  Currently I'm not sure what type SUMMER, FALL, etc. are.

Edit:

I see SUMMER, FALL, etc. are of type `Season`, so, first convert `currentSeason` to an enum, and switch on that converted value.